# Which events are invoked when an order is removed or cancelled?

Tags: commerce, event-subscribers

I have already an event subscriber class with *commerce_order.place.post_transition* defined. I need to remove nodes when an order is deleted or canceled.

What event could I use in that case?

Answer (score 2):

```
$events = [
  // State change events fired on workflow transitions from state_machine.
  'commerce_order.place.post_transition' => ['onOrderPlace', -100],
  'commerce_order.cancel.post_transition' => ['onOrderCancel', -100],
  // Order storage events dispatched during entity operations in CommerceContentEntityStorage.
  // ORDER_UPDATE handles new order items since ORDER_ITEM_INSERT doesn't.
  'commerce_order.commerce_order.update' => ['onOrderUpdate', -100],
  'commerce_order.commerce_order.predelete' => ['onOrderDelete', -100],
  /* OrderEvents::ORDER_ITEM_UPDATE => ['onOrderItemUpdate', -100],
  OrderEvents::ORDER_ITEM_DELETE => ['onOrderItemDelete', -100], */

  'commerce_payment.filter_payment_gateways' => ['onPayment', -100],
  ];
return $events;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $events['commerce_order.cancel.post_transition'] for subscribing to order cancel event.