# Event called when an order line is removed

Tags: commerce

In Drupal Commerce what event do i need to subscribe to when an order line is removed?

This questions talks about an order being removed/deleted: [Which events are invoked when an order is removed or cancelled?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264490/which-events-are-invoked-when-an-order-is-removed-or-cancelled)

The Commerce documentation also only refers to entire orders in terms of events: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/workflows/react-to-workflow-transitions

However I am not seeking an event when the entire order is removed/deleted, only when an individual line is removed/deleted from an order.

Also if I susbcribe to an event that is called when an order line is removed, will that same event be called for each line when an entire order is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the event i needed:

`commerce_order.commerce_order_item.delete`

The second part of my question I will post as a new question to make it more clear.